# Visual Studio - attach to process

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to understand what the 'Attach to process' is useful for in Visual Studio.  I am looking for a memory leak and I am finding WinDBG quite difficult to use to say the least.  I realize there are other commercial alternatives like ANT Profiler.

What is 'attach to process' used for specifically? I have searched online and have found plenty of documentation explaining what to select in Visual studio and how to use macros with this feature, but no documentation explaining what this is useful for specifically.

**UPDATE 19/06/2012 at 19:40 GMT**
I have managed to attach the Visual Studio debugger to a process running (small VB.NET program).  However, I have noticed that the PDB files don't seem to be needed i.e. I can add breakpoints and step through the code without them.  Are the PDB files needed when attaching to a process in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running an application in a different user context and need to debug it, you can attach to the process. This process can be local or remote.

Essentially it is used to debug an already running process.

Note: You do need to have the source code for this process in Visual Studio (or have a [symbol server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) that Visual Studio can use that points to the same executable).

Comment: Thanks +1 for the user context suggestion.  How do you view the source code?  I click 'attach to process', select w3wp.exe and I am faced with a blank Visual Studio window.

Comment: @w0051977 - You need to have the source code already up in Visual Studio. "Attach to Process" is not a decompiler.

Comment: I see.  I assume that you can then put in a breakpoint in Visual Studio and the process will stop at the breakpoint (like debugging a classic asp application with vb6 classes)?

Comment: @w0051977 - That's the idea. And attaching to an IIS process is (was?) one common use case (if you didn't want to use the developer web server).

Comment: One more thing.  What is the relationship between symbol files and the debugger? For example, does the symbol file have to go in the same folder as the executable? Does the application have to be built in debug mode?

Comment: @w0051977 - It doesn't have to (you can use a symbol server, for instance), but yes, that's one place the debugger will look for symbols. And no, `pdb` files will be emitted for release builds too.

Comment: one more thing (I promise). I am getting an error now when I add a breakpoint (after VS 2008 is attached to process) i.e. the breakpoint will not be hit. The source code is different from the original version. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @w0051977 - Exactly what it says. The version you are trying to attached to was compiled with a different version of your code. You need them to match.

Comment: ,No, they are identical.  I have checked and doubled checked.

Comment: @w0051977 - When I say identical, I mean the whole executable (not only the class with the breakpoint).

Comment: thanks.  I managed to successfully attach to the process (with a running executable) and step through the code in Visual Studio.  I then deleted all of the PDB files (debug and release) and it still worked.  Are the PDB files not required then?

Comment: @w0051977 - Not strictly, not if you have the source with you (or you may have the PDB files in the bin directory on your computer)

Comment: No they are not in the BIN directory.  It must be using the code in Visual Studio.